# Webform Worflow notifaction

Tags: 7, webforms, workflows

I'm using D7, WebForm Module and Workflow Module.

When the user submit, the state change automatically to the first state.

Users to notify and the submitter user should receive normally the notification.

When i try nothing received!

Can anyone suggest to me, What can i do to prevent this problem from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information on the issue, there could be a lot of causes for this. For example, most emails are sent when cron runs, is cron set to run periodically?

Are you able to see your logs on the site?

If so, are there errors associated with email not being sent (Go to http://your-site-url/#overlay=admin/reports and select recent log messages)? Is your server configured to sent emails?

Some error logs are found on your **/etc/httpd/logs/error_log** folder, looking there would be helpful too while you try and submit a form to see what gets logged.

As I mention above, more info perhaps can help us troubleshoot it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I try again to submit the web form, now I found that it works very well, with other states (which are changing manually) but the first state (which is changing automatically by the system) notifications are not sent

Comment: So it does send an email. Seems your server is configured correctly to send emails. That rules out improper configured server. The next thing we need to rule out is a wrong email address... are you able to see error messages? If not, to enable error messages on drupal, go to http://your-site-url/admin/config/development/logging and check "All messages" and click safe. Note that you will need to check "None" once you are done trouble shooting. This way we are able to see what errors you get when trying to submit our form.

Comment: i check all messages, then i submit a new form, but i can't see errors, i'm using Reroute emails module,for the first state changing automatically, i still receive nothing

Comment: Looks like they closed the question ... however, sounds like if you are not receiving errors, check your drupal logs again, but this time look foe messages pertaining "email sent" or similar. If the emails are sent, Drupal will record those events in the admin log. Dont forget to run cron each time you doing the test.